# Connect LED Cinema Display (Mini DP) via HDMI

Tags: display, macbook-pro, hdmi, cinema-display

Is there any way I can connect an LED Cinema Display via the HDMI port on my MacBook Pro with Retina display? I know there are various dongles that adapt for HDMI cables from Mini DP, but if I were to plug such an adapter into the back end of a LED Cinema Display, and connect it to my rMBP via an HDMI cake, would that configuration work?

Comment: What is HDMI cake?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an adaptor (supposedly) -- thunderbolt ports are the same as mini display ports, so [according to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#11) you do not need an adaptor, because it "will work just like it was connecting to a Mini DisplayPort connector when plugging in directly to the Thunderbolt connector on your Apple computer."

That said, I am also trying to figure out how it works, because it doesn't for me currently. But it is "supposed to".

Some links:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#11

[http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3382#3a](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#11)